# Laravel 5 randomly send 500 Internal Server Error on ajax requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my application Laravel 5 randomly send 500 Internal Server Error on ajax requests (for example, on ten 200 OK requests, one 500 Internal Server Error request). CSRF token is correctly set up:

```
$(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({

        timeout: 3000,
        headers: {

            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});
```

This is what Laravel says

[image]

How can I fix this or catch the place in code where problem located?

Comment: You should set Laravel's debug to true for a more helpful message, or check the error logs. In my experience with ajax requests, the Token error is often the culprit

Comment: @DamienPirsy APP_DEBUG=true in my application

Comment: install laravel debug toolbar, it can help you to find these kind of error, either some variable is missing in view.

Comment: I see in log [2016-02-18 10:59:36] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:31. I will try to find decision on this error.

Comment: I change my app.php section `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',` to `'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,` and then run `php artisan key:generate`. Now it is OK.

Comment: Evgeniy I also had this problem, have you any conclusions of why this is? i  do alot of ajax requests from my laravel servers and this happends from time to time, i am going to try your method

Comment: @TarreTan this method was useful at the begining. but then problem appear again. I'am upgrade Laravel, and the problem was gone.

Comment: Alright man, yeah i noticed it was almost the same as before, I did start develop in early 5.2 and did a couple of updates back in january, what are you running? what http server are you using, and also what ver on php? I am running php7 thru fcgi and nginx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random Ajax request errors are mostly throwed by config issues. Check your laravel log in `storage -> logs -> laravel.log` for what is causing the issue.

You can cache your configs by running below artisan command. It will get rid of that random error popup.

```
php artisan config:cache
```